# view using the taxonomy of an organic group

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, organic-groups

I'm trying to create a view that displays content related to the taxonomy term the group page has i.e. if you were on the groups/group1 and group1 has a taxonomy term called technology, a list of content tagged with that taxonomy term would be displayed.

Thanks to a previous question I found out how to get arguments from the URL. But i'm not sure how I can use views to capture a taxonomy term related to a given group. Can you use views 2 to take the url query the database to get the taxonomy term and then use that as the argument for the view?

Comment: have you tried relationships. that is for these kind of things

Comment: can you elaborate, how do you set up a relationship in views. I'm trying to leverage the fact that each group has a taxonomy attached to it, and use this as an argument to get content tagged with that taxonomy.

Comment: could you explain the setup you have at the moment

Comment: currently the view takes an organic group as its argument and returns the content tagged as events related to that group. What I want to do is expand on this so it pulls in content of groups with the same category as the group. i.e. if the group was part of the technology taxonomy I would want all events tagged as technology to appear as well.

Comment: you would add a relationship taxonomy term. then you would add another relationship called content has taxonomy term and use the previous relationship. and add the contents with the second relationship.

Comment: I don't have the option to add a "has" option under relationships, is there any documentation on this.